# Is my story over?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I LOVE NMS but the story is extremely confusing (I think I get the gist) so I'm not sure if I've finished it as I still have two main missions showing in the log.

> I switched galaxy for the first time and now there are no Atlas stations that I can see, and black holes just send me to random locations so I'm not sure what to do, story-wise. I've also learned the Atlas has 16 minutes left, so is that the end?

**If there IS more, no spoilers please**, just tell me the general direction I need to go to continue.

Additional:

> I put Artimus in the Simulation machine on the Anomaly. I warped around visiting Atlas stations, building Atlas Seeds as I went. I have yet to create the Rememberance Seed (Part of why I thought there should be more). I think I remember The Purge being mentioned. It said I needed to shut off The Atlas to restart it and I selected a green couloured galaxy(; the "Tranquil" one) the last time I was on the Atlas when I think I shut it off.

Comment: Have you finished a mission called The Purge? That should be the final story mission of the Artemis Path.

Comment: I didn't know there were other paths. I added additional info anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the ending is mentioned I will use spoilers too.

> The main story quest in NMS is the one called "Artemis Path". The Atlas seed gathering task is actually another unrelated quest commonly called "Atlas Path". While the two are obviously related at lore level - both are about the Atlas- they are otherwise separate as far as gameplay is concerned.
>
>  The Artemis Path final steps - The Purge & New Beginning - do indeed end with the choice of either "resetting" the simulation and traveling to a new galaxy (notice that on a pure gameplay level the old galaxy is not deleted an for example still available from the portals at every space station) or just staying in the current one. Either way, **that is the end of the main plot** (---notice: I think you are still able to return later to reset the simulation if you refuse the first time, but I don't know if this is still the case--- be carefull, even if the game hints that you can come back and change you choice later if you refuse to reset the simulation... you can't. You are still able to travel to the *next* galaxy in the sequence from the galaxy center but you have only this opportunity to jump to a *random* galaxy of a specific type of your choice).
>  Coincidentally, this is one of the two standard ways to go to a different galaxy outside co-op / portal abuse - the other being reaching the Galaxy Core. While the core can be reached multiple times, the Atlas Path can be completed only once.
>
>
>  That said it is worth noticing that the old community weekend missions available from the Anomaly had some sort of basic plot that somehow tried to follow up on the main one. Currently, that seems to be on hold in favor of the expedition feature. The old missions seemed to point to the nature of the "red glass"  that haunted Artemis, but so far nothing else has been revealed. I suspect that the next story advancement will be made in a still-to-come expedition in a big future update that may introduce some sort of Atlas related enemy but those are only speculation.

So, what can you do now?

> - explore the new Outpost feature and build a city with actual NPC.
>  - join the expedition mode when is available. Requires starting a new save and is more of a speedrun even with a set duration
>  - do other quests you may have missed like the Living Egg one, Abyss one etc
>  - complete the Atlas path if you don't have already.
>  - just do what you like... base building, getting the perfect companion egg etc...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have 2 questions about this. 1. Did I miss anything by taking the path I did? And 2. Do I need to build the Rememberance Seed for anything? (I need "Day..[something]" or "[something]...day" to build it.)

Comment: @n00dles the path you took is the only path to the end of the game. There is no alternate route if that is what you are asking. The final choice has no real influence either - if you reset the simulation you get  free jump to another galaxy, if you refuse you basically put the thing "on hold" until you decide to jump. Every other choice before is also "fake"- Artemis, coordinate given to Apollo... those are just to change the dialogues the Atlas give

Comment: Whatever you did with Artemis, has no consequences. Whatever happened to Apollo has no consequences either. Up to now, there is no way to save Artemis, nor to actually meet Apollo. Weekend missions have a plot, but it is just a big crescendo of hints to something that never actually happened in game so far.

Comment: @n00dles BTW, since you mention the Remembrance seed, I don't get the "Day" part - should just need some resources - if you have issues with that maybe post a separate question. As for the use, it a) give you more health and b) allows you to interact with some specific terminals that give you some additional lore. Before you ask, the terminal only give you test and aren't tied to any further event/quest.

Comment: Thanks man :) I probably got the "day" part wrong.